# Exception value error: takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

When I run my code I am getting this errors: 
In my URL patterns, if I write like this: `path('', views.home, name='home'),` I'm getting "**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" error.
If I  write like this: `path('', views.home.as_view, name='home'),` I'm getting this error: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
Below is my class view:

```
class home(ListView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = Pull_Requests
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pull_Requests.objects.all()
```

And below is my home.html file

```
{% block body %}
       <div class="container">
            {% for field in object_list %}
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ field.pr_project  }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.pr_id }} </th>
                        <th>{{ field.nd_comments }} </th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_added_lines_code }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_deleted_lines_code }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_commits }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.nb_changed_fies }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.Closed_status }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.reputation }}</th>
                        <th>{{ field.Label }}</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            {% empty %}
                <strong> There is no pull request in the database. </strong>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ***`Class Based View`***. So you have to call the view with [**`.as_view()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) method. So in your urls.py it should be as

```
path('', views.home.as_view(), name='home')
```